# Accessing a value in a tuple that is in a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
[(1,2), (2,3), (4,5), (3,4), (6,7), (6,7), (3,8)]
```

How do I return the 2nd value from each tuple inside this list?

Desired output:

```
[2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

With a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
[x[1] for x in L]
```

Comment: I understand this is a simple question. Is SO such an elitist place? Try googling the question, the results are not what I need. I did learning python the hard way and i didn't find this in there. I've asked questions before about the the best approach to learning Python and the unanimous answer is to get a basic book and just dive in. It frustrates me as well as I just cannot find the solution in any book or online material I have search for so far? Plus your comment really isn't helpful and discourages newbies new members from posting on SO.

Comment: @Nai: I suggest to read the Python tutorial: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html . In general, the documentation is very good. And sometimes, one just has to try ;)

Comment: I Googled "accessing item in tuple" with the intent of accessing an item in a tuple list. It brought me to your question so thank you. I am fairly new to Python and don't find the answer particularly intuitive, but that's just me!

Comment: I thought the entire concept with SO was to make it easier to find answers to your questions. Why must a question be of a certain difficulty in order to be valid? Good question, good answer.

Comment: Brilliant! A short, sharp, to the point answer to a short, sharp, to the point question. You both just made my day!

Answer (score 85):

Ignacio's answer is what you want. However, as someone also learning Python, let me try to dissect it for you... As mentioned, it is a list comprehension (covered in [DiveIntoPython3](http://diveintopython3.org/comprehensions.html#listcomprehension), for example). Here are a few points:

`[x[1] for x in L]`

- Notice the `[]`'s around the line of code. These are what define a list. This tells you that this code returns a list, so it's of the `list` type. Hence, this technique is called a "list comprehension."
- L is your original list. So you should define `L = [(1,2),(2,3),(4,5),(3,4),(6,7),(6,7),(3,8)]` prior to executing the above code.
- `x` is a variable that only exists in the comprehension - try to access `x` outside of the comprehension, or type `type(x)` after executing the above line and it will tell you `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`, whereas `type(L)` returns `<class 'list'>`.
- `x[1]` points to the *second* item in each of the tuples whereas `x[0]` would point to each of the first items.
- So this line of code literally reads "return the second item in a tuple for all tuples in list L."

It's tough to tell how much you attempted the problem prior to asking the question, but perhaps you just weren't familiar with comprehensions? I would spend some time reading through [Chapter 3 of DiveIntoPython](http://diveintopython3.org/comprehensions.html), or any resource on comprehensions. Good luck.

Comment: In 2.x, `x` will exist outside of the LC, with the last value bound to it. This is fixed in 3.x.

Comment: Awesome explanation @gary. I appreciate especially your pointing out what L refers to.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @PatrickWilliams. I'm glad this helps. You could also do `[x[1] for x in [(1,2),(2,3),(4,5),(3,4),(6,7),(6,7),(3,8)]]` but it's not as easy on the eyes.

Answer (score 5):

A list comprehension is absolutely the way to do this. Another way that *should* be faster is `map` and `itemgetter`.

```
import operator

new_list = map(operator.itemgetter(1), old_list)
```

In response to the comment that the OP couldn't find an answer on google, I'll point out a super naive way to do it.

```
new_list = []
for item in old_list:
    new_list.append(item[1])
```

This uses:

1. Declaring a variable to reference an empty list.
2. A for loop.
3. Calling the `append` method on a list.

If somebody is trying to learn a language and can't put together these basic pieces for themselves, then they need to *view it as an exercise* and do it themselves even if it takes twenty hours.

One needs to learn how to *think about what one wants* and compare that to *the available tools*. Every element in my second answer should be covered in a basic tutorial. **You cannot learn to program without reading one**.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use sequence unpacking with `zip`:

```
L = [(1,2),(2,3),(4,5),(3,4),(6,7),(6,7),(3,8)]

_, res = zip(*L)

print(res)

# (2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 7, 8)
```

This also creates a tuple `_` from the discarded first elements. Extracting only the second is possible, but more verbose:

```
from itertools import islice

res = next(islice(zip(*L), 1, None))
```

Answer (score 2):

OR you can use `pandas`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> L = [(1,2),(2,3),(4,5),(3,4),(6,7),(6,7),(3,8)]
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(L)
>>> df[1]
0    2
1    3
2    5
3    4
4    7
5    7
6    8
Name: 1, dtype: int64
>>> df[1].tolist()
[2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 7, 8]
>>>
```

Or `numpy`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> L = [(1,2),(2,3),(4,5),(3,4),(6,7),(6,7),(3,8)]
>>> arr=np.array(L)
>>> arr.T[1]
array([2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 7, 8])
>>> arr.T[1].tolist()
[2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 7, 8]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [(0,2), (4,3), (9,9), (10,-1)]
print(list(map(lambda item: item[1], a)))
```

Comment: Please explain your answer a bit so it gets easier to understand for others searching for it.