# Finding the minimum value from a tuple list

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to coding and need to find the minimum value from a list of tuples.

```
def min_steps(step_records):
    """ random """
    if step_records != []:
        for steps in step_records:
            day, step = steps
            result = min(step)
    else:
        result = None
    return result
```

This results in an error:

> 'int' object is not iterable

How do I return the `min` if the list is something like this?

```
step_records = [('2010-01-01',1),
                ('2010-01-02',2),
                ('2010-01-03',3)]
```

Comment: Please, edit your question and format code so it would be easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

`tuples` can be indexed (see: [Accessing a value in a tuple that is in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800811/accessing-a-value-in-a-tuple-that-is-in-a-list)).

Using that we can create a list from those indices and call minimum like you had done:

```
def min_steps(step_records):
    """ random """
    if step_records:
        result = min([step[1] for step in step_records]) # min([1,2,3])
    else:
        result = None
    return result

step_records = [('2010-01-01',1),
                ('2010-01-02',2),
                ('2010-01-03',3)]

print(min_steps(step_records))
```

output:

```
1
```