# Retrieve a range of values from list

Tags: python, list, data-retrieval

I'm wondering if I have a list of the list like this:

```
a = [[43,76],[8,3],[22,80],[71,9]]
```

If I want to retrieve the second value in the last 3 sub-lists, i.e the second value from index 1 to 3 would be like that:

```
a[1:3][1]:

3
80
9
```

Comment: `[x[1] for x in a[1:3]]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing a value in a tuple that is in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800811/accessing-a-value-in-a-tuple-that-is-in-a-list)

Comment: Not exactly @sahasrara62

Comment: @LamaMo i think it is same if you add the list slicing operation also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My 2c:

```
[x[1] for x in a[-3:]]
```

---

```
[3, 80, 9]
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/d1dc7e25e6)

Answer (score 1):

You can use *negative slicing* here.

```
print(*[x[1] for x in a[-3:]],sep='\n') #a[-3:] gives last 3 elements
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that gets evaluated like this:

`a[1:3][1]` -> `[[8, 3], [22, 80]][1]` -> `[22, 80]`

Note that `:3` means *up to* index 3 (not including it), so really your slice should be `a[1:4]`, but where you want the *last three* sublists, and not the *second to fourth* sublists, you should use a negative slice: `a[-3:]`. Even if the list can only ever be 4-long, this is clearer.

So you want `[x[1] for x in a[-3:]]`

If you want to print them like in your example output:

```
>>> for x in a[-3:]:
...     print(x[1])
... 
3
80
9
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote... Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the easiest way to do this as most of the other answers have suggested is:

```
[x[1] for x in a[-3:]]
```

However, for practice and for getting used to other ways of solving problems involving lists (and others), it is good to read up on what `map`, `filter` and `reduce` do (assuming that it is not known already). A small description is [here](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html).

I thought I'd leave this answer here to add to the other answers. This is another way to do it using `map`.

```
[*map(lambda x: x[1], a[-3:])]

Output: [3, 80, 9]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure why this got down voted, as well as some other valid answers in this question. Please provide an explanation for the down vote.