# How to get certain tuples nested in a list by calling only the first element?

Tags: python, list, nested, tuples

```
noodles = [(‘Samyang’, ‘Korea’, ’50’), (‘Nissin Cup Noodle’, ‘Japan’, ’70’), (‘Jin Mai Lang’, ‘China’, ’40’)]
```

For example, I only want Nissin Cup Noodle. The output should look like:

`Nissin Cup Noodle, Japan, 70`

Comment: Try `noodles[1]` to get the second element in the list or `noodles[1][0]` if you want Nissin Cup Noodle only, the first element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing a value in a tuple that is in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800811/accessing-a-value-in-a-tuple-that-is-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to find the index of the a particular entry in a list of tuples based on the first coordinate.

```
noodles = [('Samyang', 'Korea', '50'), ('Nissin Cup Noodle', 'Japan', '70'), ('Jin Mai Lang', 'China', '40')]
names   = [item[0] for item in noodles]
index   = names.index('Nissin Cup Noodle')

print(noodles[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension and a `[0]` index...

```
noodles = [(‘Samyang’, ‘Korea’, ’50’), (‘Nissin Cup Noodle’, ‘Japan’, ’70’), (‘Jin Mai Lang’, ‘China’, ’40’)]
nissan = 'Nissin Cup Noodle'
n_c_n = [(x, y, z) for x, y, z in noodles if x == nissan][0]
```

or a for loop:

```
noodles = [(‘Samyang’, ‘Korea’, ’50’), (‘Nissin Cup Noodle’, ‘Japan’, ’70’), (‘Jin Mai Lang’, ‘China’, ’40’)]
nissan = 'Nissin Cup Noodle'
for noodle in noodles:
    if noodle[0] == nissan:
        n_c_n = noodle
        break
```

But you probably should be using a dict instead if you want to find elements based on a key, you can unpack the tuple with `*` into a tuple including the key to get your desires tuple of all three:

```
noodles = {‘Samyang’: (‘Korea’, ’50’), ‘Nissin Cup Noodle’: (‘Japan’, ’70’), ‘Jin Mai Lang’: (‘China’, ’40’)}
nissan = 'Nissin Cup Noodle'
n_c_n = (nissan, *noodles[nissan])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the values in a tuple directly to variables and print them that way too:

```
for noodle_type, country, num in noodles:
    print(f”{noodle_type}, {country}, {num}”)
```

Throw an if statement in there if you only want to print out a specific tuple

```
for noodle_type, country, num in noodles:
    if noodle_type == “whatever”:
        print(f”{noodle_type}, {country}, {num}”)
```