# Accessing values of tuples inside lists in if statements

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tuples, list-comprehension

python beginner here. [According to this thread,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800811/accessing-a-value-in-a-tuple-that-is-in-a-list), I learned how to access values of tuples inside lists.

This is the answer in the thread above:

```
[x[1] for x in L]
```

I have a list of tuples here:

```
[('w', False), ('o', True), ('r', False), ('d', False)]
```

I would like to read the True/False value in each tuple and print an underscore if the value is false and print the character if the value is true. For example, in the above list, since `'o'` is the item that is True, I would like to print `_o__`.

This is what I have been trying so far, and I feel like I'm in the right direction, but since I'm writing this thread, it obviously doesn't work:

```
for char in word: #part i need help on
  if [x[1] for x in word] == True:
    print("_", end="")
  elif [x[1] for x in word] == False:
    print(word[char], end="")
```

This is the entire code if more info is needed (beginnings of a Hangman game, long way to go), but specifically I need help with the above block of code:

```
randomword = "word" #will add random words when it works properly
word = [(char, False) for char in randomword] #splits randomword into list of tuples of different characters with a false value assigned because no letters have been guessed yet

def getLetter(): #letter guessing function, limits input to one character
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ")
    if len(guess) != 1 or (guess.isalpha()) == False:
        while len(guess) != 1 or (guess.isalpha()) == False: 
            print("Must be" + "\033[96m one letter!" + "\033[0m Try again.")
            guess = input("Guess a letter: ")
    return guess

guess = getLetter()

for char in range(word.__len__()):
  if word[char][0] == guess.lower():
    word[char] = (guess, True) #a correct guess changes the False to True
print(word) 

for char in word: #part i need help on
  if [x[1] for x in word] == True:
    print("_", end="")
  elif [x[1] for x in word] == False:
    print(word[char])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you kind of overcomplicated that. Instead try something like this.

```
lst = [('w', False), ('o', True), ('r', False), ('d', False)]
for tup in lst:
  if tup[1] == True:
      print(tup[0],end="")
  elif tup[1] == False:
    print('_', end="")
```

Comment: All you need is `else`.  `if tup[1]:` / `print(tup[0],end='')` / `else:` / `print('_',end='')`

Comment: this is a lot simpler and easier to understand, thank you!

Comment: @TimRoberts, yes I know that. But I wanted to keep it there because the OP had it.  Maybe lst's tuples might contain something other than a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Using List comprehension this can be done as :

```
word = [('w', False), ('o', True), ('r', False), ('d', False)]
new_word = [elements[0] if elements[1]==True else "_" for elements in word]
for element in new_word:
    print(element,end="")
```

Here turn-by-turn elements of a list are extracted and as it is a tuple that has two elements their 1st index is checked for true or false and depending upon the value either character or _ is assigned, which is done using the ternary operator in python.

Comment: You could use something like this to make it a one-liner `''.join([elements[0] if elements[1]==True else "_" for elements in word])`. `for` loop at the end is inefficient:)